# Wpf Multiple nested Usercontrols with MvvmCross

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvmcross

I'm pretty new in `MvvmCross` but I'm working with `mvvm` for awhile. I know how to compose usercontrols with nested usercontrols. Now with `mvvmcross` I got stucked to show two or more usercontrols in another usercontrol. I don't use any other framework than `MvvmCross`.
My Rootview looks like this:

```
`<views:MvxWpfView
    x:Class="MvvmCrossTest.Wpf.Views.RootView"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <DockPanel>  
        <TextBlock Text="Root" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainMenuVM" Content="{Binding MainMenuVM}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    </DockPanel>
</views:MvxWpfView>`
```

The corresponding ViewModel looks like this:

```
using MvvmCross.Commands;
using MvvmCross.Logging;
using MvvmCross.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTest.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class RootViewModel: MvxNavigationViewModel
    {
        private readonly IMvxViewModelLoader _mvxViewModelLoader;
        public RootViewModel(IMvxLogProvider logProvider, IMvxNavigationService navigationService, IMvxViewModelLoader mvxViewModelLoader) : base(logProvider, navigationService)
        {
            _mvxViewModelLoader = mvxViewModelLoader;
            ShowMainMenu();
        }

        private MainMenuViewModel _mainMenuVM;

        public MainMenuViewModel MainMenuVM
        {
            get { return _mainMenuVM; }
            set 
            {
                SetProperty(ref _mainMenuVM, value);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MainMenuVM);
            }
        }

         public MvxCommand ShowMainMenuCommand { get; set; }

        public void ShowMainMenu()
        {
            MainMenuVM = (MainMenuViewModel)_mvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel(MvxViewModelRequest.GetDefaultRequest(typeof(MainMenuViewModel)), null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The simplified View I want to show in the contentcontrol looks like this:

```
<views:MvxWpfView
    x:Class="MvvmCrossTest.Wpf.Views.MainMenuView"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Aqua"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
            
    </Grid>
</views:MvxWpfView>
```

And also the corresponding ViewModel.

```
using MvvmCross.Logging;
using MvvmCross.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTest.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class MainMenuViewModel : MvxNavigationViewModel
    {
        public MainMenuViewModel(IMvxLogProvider logProvider, IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(logProvider, navigationService)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Instead of the View/ViewModel I see a text that says "MvvmCrossTest.Core.ViewModels.MainMenuViewModel".

I don't want to use Xamarin!

Comment: I don't see [data template](https://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) definition to map `MainMenuViewModel` to `views:MvxWpfView`.

Comment: I was searching the internet for days and it seems that MvvmCross is wiring up Views and ViewModels automatically. I couldn't find any example with a datatemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [project](https://github.com/tuke307/samples) where I show you some basics.

## simple

You can find the samples [here](https://github.com/tuke307/Samples/tree/master/MvvmCross.WPF.View1).

the `RootView`;

```xml
<views:MvxWpfView xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeProject.Views" ...>
     <Grid>
           <Label Content="Hello from RootView" />
           <local:NestedView />    
     </Grid>
</views:MvxWpfView>
```

the `NestedView`;

```xml
<views:MvxWpfView ...>
     <Grid>
           <Label Content="Hello from NestedView" />  
     </Grid>
</views:MvxWpfView>
```

## extended (custom presenter)

With this custom wpf presenter you can easily navigate to views while specified themn in a container. With that, you can close and open views from the view model while using the mvvmcross navigation service.

I copied this from another [project](https://github.com/eiadxp/MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.ItemsViewPresenter). You can find the whole implementation in my sample project [here](https://github.com/tuke307/Samples/tree/master/MvvmCross.WPF.View2).

the `RootView`;

```xml
<views:MvxWpfView ...>
      <Grid>
           <Label Content="Hello" />
           <ItemsControl region:MvxContainer.Id="RootViewRegion"/>    
      </Grid>
</views:MvxWpfView>
```

the `RootView` code behind;

```
[MvxContentPagePresentation(WrapInNavigationPage = true, NoHistory = false)]
public partial class RootView: MvxWpfView<RootViewModel>
{
     public RootView()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
     }
}
```

the `RootViewModel`;

```
public class RootViewModel: MvxNavigationViewModel
{
      private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

      public IMvxAsyncCommand ShowNestedViewModelCommand { get; protected set; }

      public RootViewModel(IMvxLogProvider logProvider, IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(logProvider, navigationService)
      {
            this._navigationService = navigationService;
    
            // navigate to nested view
            this.ShowNestedViewModelCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(() => this._navigationService.Navigate<NestedViewModel>());

            ShowNestedViewModelCommand.Execute();
      }
}
```

the `NestedView` code behind;

```
[MvxWpfPresenter("RootViewRegion", mvxViewPosition.NewOrExsist)]
public partial class NestedView : MvxWpfView<NestedViewModel>
{
    public NestedView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

## good to know

when you have problems with navigation and view model connection use this code behind. It loads the viewmodel for the specific view;

```
[MvxContentPagePresentation(WrapInNavigationPage = true, NoHistory = false)]
public partial class SomeView : MvxWpfView<ViewModels.SomeViewModel>
{
    public SomeView()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    
         if (!(ViewModel is ViewModels.SomeViewModel))
         {
              if (Mvx.IoCProvider.TryResolve<ViewModels.SomeViewModel>(out var someViewModel))
              {
                   ViewModel = someViewModel;
                   return;
              }
    
              var _viewModelLoader = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
              var request = new MvxViewModelInstanceRequest(typeof(ViewModels.SomeViewModel));
              request.ViewModelInstance = _viewModelLoader.LoadViewModel(request, null);
              ViewModel = request.ViewModelInstance as ViewModels.SomeViewModel;
    
              Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<ViewModels.SomeViewModel>(ViewModel);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try this as soon as possible and will give feedback if it works.

Comment: nice to hear. would you mark my answer as accepted or do you have further questions?

Answer (score 0):

> it seems that MvvmCross is wiring up Views and ViewModels automatically

I know nothing about MvvmCross, but for "automatically" to work there should be an agreement and rules, e.g. attributes or matching names (xViewModel <-> xView). Currently there is nothing I can see what connects `MainMenuViewModel` with `views:MvxWpfView`.

Anyway what you see

> I see a text that says "MvvmCrossTest.Core.ViewModels.MainMenuViewModel"

is the view trying to visualize non-control as text due to missing data template.

It's easy to fix by just adding data template

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainMenuViewModel}">
    <views:MvxWpfView />
</DataTemplate>
```

somewhere (e.g. into `views:MvxWpfView.Resources`) and the view will be displayed.

Comment: I know how to work with Datatemplates in MVVM and Wpf, but MvxWpfView doesn't support Resources.

Comment: @Pete63, it doesn't have to be `views:MvxWpfView.Resources`. Define data template in in App.xaml, in one of upper containers (e.g. `Grid`) resources or directly in `ContentControl` resources, etc.