# MVVMCross How to display a view within a view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvvmcross

I'm a new to the MVVMCross package, and C# for that matter.  I've spent the better part of the day trying to figure out what I'm not understanding reading the documentation on presenters and navigation, etc. in order to try to understand, but I'm missing something.

I originally created a WPF app not implementing MVVM and now I wanted to convert, but I'm struggling with this part.  I want to have a Main Menu that is part of a grid in a "MainWindow" like shell where the remaining portion of the page (and grid column 2) are used to display a nested view.

Ultimately, I’m just trying to reproduce the same layered controls in the original WPF application.  In that app there is a content control Which takes up most of the form whose content property is set to a different form depending on the users selection.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : MvxWindow
{
    public MainWindow(IMvxNavigationService navService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel(navService);

        //content.Content = new AdminMenuView();

    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
    private MvxViewModel _nextMenuContent;

    public MainViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navService)
    {
        _navService = navService;            
        MoveMenuCommand = new MvxCommand(MoveMenu);
        ChildViewModel = new AdminMenuViewModel();
        GoToAdminMenu = new MvxCommand(SelectAdminMenu);

    }
```

MainView.xaml

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ChildViewModel}"/>
```

***The grid and columns are all working fine

MainView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainView : MvxWpfView
{
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
}
```

AdminMenuModel.cs

```
public class AdminMenuViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navService;

    public AdminMenuViewModel()
    {
        Initialize();
        
    }

    public override void Prepare()
    {
        base.Prepare();
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        await base.Initialize();
    }



}
```

AdminMenuModel.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class AdminMenuView : MvxWpfView
{
    public AdminMenuView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public new AdminMenuViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return base.ViewModel as AdminMenuViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

}
```

When I call the AdminMenuViewModel it runs, but all I get in the content control is either a blank screen if I Bind the "ChildViewModel" to the DataContext property of the content control and a string of the path to the AdminMenuViewModel if I bind it to the content property.

Comment: this question was already been asked. [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65319108/12543744) see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319108/wpf-multiple-nested-usercontrols-with-mvvmcross/65339667#65339667)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set MainViewModel as DataContext of your main window

```
public MainWindow(IMvxNavigationService navService)
{
    DataContext = new MainViewModel(navService);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: I tried your modifications, but I get the following error "MissingMethodException: No default constructor found for type 'MvxStarter.WPF.MainWindow'."  It starts fine without it.  Assuming that was supposed to go in the code behind for the MainWindow.xaml which has no ViewModel.  What am I missing?

Comment: made an edit.  I noticed that I pasted the MainWindow in the MainView.xaml.cs section.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I don't know how things work in MVVMCross but MainWindow expects IMvxNavigationService passed to it. are you using dependency injection to get that ? is that configured ?

Comment: It didn’t help?

Comment: You can use WpfSnoop and check if DataContext set on your window. Also you can see binding error in VS Output window.