# How to close a navigated child view from the main view in MVVMCross?

Tags: wpf, navigation, mvvmcross

I'am pretty new in MVVMCross and I am using MVVMCross 8.0.2 for a **WPF** application. Basically what I'am trying to do is to have main view that have mode selections for the application. When i change the mode selection (with buttons) views shown on the main view should change. I used **Mvx.Wpf.ItemsPresenter** library for this purpose. I used the sample project provided in this answer: [sample project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65339667)

In the main view I created a MvxContainer region inside a border. Two different views share the same region

```
<Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5" >
        <ItemsControl region:MvxContainer.Id="NestedViewRegion"> </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

Navigation works as shown in this figure:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBJRh.png)

Red region is the main view, blue region is the child views i am navigating. **Problem is that when i navigate with the buttons, both child views are added to the region.** What i want to do is to close one of them by using the same buttons which belongs to the main view.

For ex.: when i click navigate 1 button, first child view should appear, after i click the navigate 2 button first child view should close and second child view should appear.

I tried to use MvxPresentationHint to achieve that but i think it can just close the child view within the child viewmodel. Code below shows the navigation commands attached to buttons, this code is in the main viewmodel.

```
    public async Task FirstNavigateCommand()
    {
        //await _navigationService.ChangePresentation(new MvxClosePresentationHint());
        await _navigationService.Navigate<NestedViewModel>();
    }

    public async Task SecondNavigateCommand()
    {
        //
        await _navigationService.Navigate<NestedNestedViewModel>();
    }
```

I also tried to use Messenger plugin but couldn't manage to work with navigationservice.

If anyone have any ideas on how to close a navigated view from the main view, i would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved with the help of the owner of the sample project. Solution is using the GUI commands, which are explained in the [Mvx.Wpf.ItemsPresenter github repository.](https://github.com/eiadxp/MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.ItemsViewPresenter)

By adding the behaviors namespace and using the interaction triggers with the GUI commands solved my problem. Namespace below should be added to view.

> ```
>          xmlns:i = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
> ```

Then interaction triger is added to the button content.

```
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Static region:MvxWpfPresenter.CloseViewCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="NestedViewRegion">
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>`
```

CloseViewCommand is executed when the button is clicked, which closes the last view inside the region.